# Manage images on Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, xcode, assets

I'm working on a game for Android/IOS/Web/Windows/Mac/Linux. Currently, my application use large textures for development (2048*2048 everywhere). My game is done at 95%, so I think it's time to think about resolutions and packaging.

**Here is what I've got in my head:**

```
Textures:
- XHD* : (100%) (ex: 2048*1048) (Ipad retina, Device with high resolution/DPI)
-  HD* : (50%)  (ex: 1024*1024) (New smartphones + desktop + web + Ipad < 3)
-  SD  : (25%)  (ex:  512*512)  (Old smartphone: android < 3.0 + old Iphones)
- XSD  : (12%)  (ex:  256*256)  (Very very old smartphones: Probably useless)

* For new devices, we need to have subfolders with textures in PVR, ETC1 and PNG
```

My question is:

- **How can I manage that with Eclipse (Android) / Xcode (IOS)?**

I heard about multiples APK support for android (Download the right apk from the store), so I think it's ok here. The problem is with XCode/IOS.

One of the idea was to download right assets from a server at first run, but we need a server (Impossible for now).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at Android Developers [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities By
>   default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif
>   files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at
>   the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your
>   application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium
>   screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a
>   high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density
>   screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure
>   your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions
>   at different resolutions for different screen densities. The
>   configuration qualifiers you can use for density-specific resources
>   are ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi (high), and xhdpi (extra high).
>   For example, bitmaps for high-density screens should go in
>   drawable-hdpi/. The size and density configuration qualifiers
>   correspond to the generalized sizes and densities described in Range
>   of screens supported, above.
>
> Note: If you're not familiar with configuration qualifiers and how the
>   system uses them to apply alternative resources, read Providing
>   Alternative Resources for more information.
>
> At runtime, the system ensures the best possible display on the
>   current screen with the following procedure for any given resource:
>
> The system uses the appropriate alternative resource Based on the size
>   and density of the current screen, the system uses any size- and
>   density-specific resource provided in your application. For example,
>   if the device has a high-density screen and the application requests a
>   drawable resource, the system looks for a drawable resource directory
>   that best matches the device configuration. Depending on the other
>   alternative resources available, a resource directory with the hdpi
>   qualifier (such as drawable-hdpi/) might be the best match, so the
>   system uses the drawable resource from this directory. If no matching
>   resource is available, the system uses the default resource and scales
>   it up or down as needed to match the current screen size and density
>   The "default" resources are those that are not tagged with a
>   configuration qualifier. For example, the resources in drawable/ are
>   the default drawable resources. The system assumes that default
>   resources are designed for the baseline screen size and density, which
>   is a normal screen size and a medium density. As such, the system
>   scales default density resources up for high-density screens and down
>   for low-density screens, as appropriate. However, when the system is
>   looking for a density-specific resource and does not find it in the
>   density-specific directory, it won't always use the default resources.
>   The system may instead use one of the other density-specific resources
>   in order to provide better results when scaling. For example, when
>   looking for a low-density resource and it is not available, the system
>   prefers to scale-down the high-density version of the resource,
>   because the system can easily scale a high-density resource down to
>   low-density by a factor of 0.5, with fewer artifacts, compared to
>   scaling a medium-density resource by a factor of 0.75. For more
>   information about how Android selects alternative resources by
>   matching configuration qualifiers to the device configuration, read
>   How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource.

This could also help you:

You need to create different layout for diff screen size. Support all screen you need to create following layout:

Low density Small screens QVGA 240x320 (120dpi):

```
layout-small-ldpi (240x320)  
layout-small-land-ldpi (320x240)
```

Low density Normal screens WVGA400 240x400 (x432) (120dpi):

```
layout-ldpi  (240 x 400 )
layout-land-ldpi  (400 x 240 )
```

Medium density Normal screens HVGA 320x480 (160dpi):

```
layout-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-land-mdpi (480 x 320 )
```

Medium density Large screens HVGA 320x480 (160dpi):

```
layout-large-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-large-land-mdpi (480 x 320)
```

Galaxy Tab ( 240 dpi ):

```
layout-large  (600 x 1024) 
layout-large-land  (1024 x 600)
```

High density Normal screens WVGA800 480x800 (x854) (240 dpi):

```
layout-hdpi (480 x 800)
layout-land-hdpi (800 x 480)
```

Xoom (medium density large but 1280x800 res) (160 dpi):

```
layout-xlarge (800 x 1280)
layout-xlarge-land (1280 x 800)
```

Also add following code in .manifest file:

```
<supports-screens                                 
    android:smallScreens="true"                    
    android:normalScreens="true"         
    android:largeScreens="true"            
    android:xlargeScreens="true"             
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

For IOS you can use xcassets.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

It is pretty easy to use and there is a lot of info in the documentation